# When does `getTargetRanges()` return more than one range?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, inputevent

When using a `beforeinput` of type `InputEvent` you can query the `getTargetRanges()` which return an array of static ranges that will be affected by the input event.

What's an example scenario in which `getTargetRanges()` will return *more* than one range? Or does it return an array 'just in case' there will be such an event in the future? Reason for asking is that I would like to properly test code that relies on the return value of `getTargetRanges()`.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/getTargetRanges
Spec: https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#overview

---

Playground:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('beforeinput', (event) => {
  console.log(event.inputType, event.getTargetRanges().length);
  if (event.getTargetRanges().length > 1) {
    alert('how?');
  }
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <p>This is a tyypo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple selections are one example. E.g. in Firefox, double-click on a word, hold down Ctrl/Command, double-click on another word, backspace.

Comment: Yeah, we disable those in our full product, so I totally didn't think of those. Nice catch! Thank you ️